# retrofit post response is incorrect

Tags: android, post, retrofit, okhttp

this is how to call login method.

```
public static Observable<ResponseBody> login(String id, String password) {

ApiService apiService = ApiServiceGenerator.generate(ApiService.class);


return apiService.login("%2F", id, password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

and this is interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login_check")
Observable<ResponseBody> login(@Field("url") String url, @Field("mb_id") String id, @Field("mb_password") String password);
```

there "%2F" is `<input type="hidden" name="url" value="%2F">` in html

in Postman chrome extension, i could success to login.

but in android, i couldn't.

What did I miss?

Comment: is it a post method or get method

Comment: its a post. i use annotation @POST

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Comment: you dont need to add %2F

Comment: yes i tried remove %2F. but result is same

Comment: What does it mean "I couldn't"? Do you get an error/exception?

Comment: @user2340612 because of redirection, i couldnt get response of /login_check, just 302 error code. so i set okhttpclient.setfollowredirection(false). it works nice. thank you for your comment.

Comment: Maybe it may be useful to post your solution as an answer, in case other users face the same issue

Comment: @user2340612 I see. i'll don't forget to do so.